# Python Numpy unknown Syntax Error while defining function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm creating a non-visual tic tac toe game with numpy, and I have no idea what is wrong with this:

```
def possibilities(board):
    un_occupied = np.where(board == 0)
    return list(zip(not_occupied[0], not_occupied[1]))

possibilities(board)
```

The Error:

```
File "", line 5
    possibilities(board):
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: This works for me. Also you have un_occupied and not_occupied shouldn't it be the same ?

Comment: This code does not have a syntax error, it's somewhere else, very likely in the line directly above (e.g. forgot a closing parenthesis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code you have provided has perfect syntax. The error is being triggered by some other part of your code before the line 5. Check the lines 1-4 for any mistakes.

For example, the following piece of code would return syntax error similar to yours. Notice that the mistake is on the first line, where the print-function does not have a closing bracket. A good text editor will highlight the bug at the correct location.

```
print(
def foo(bar):
    return bar
```

output:

```
File "test.py", line 2
  def foo(bar):
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I figured it out there an error in my preceding for loop.